# Simple Regular Expression pattern, extract numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to extract the number(s) from in between the square brackets in a string like this:

```
"Item5Line[14].Id"
```

What I have so far causes an error in Javascript:

```
index = Id.attr('name').match(/\[\d\d?\d?\]);
```

I'm very new to regular expressions, so please be gentle :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `index = Id.attr('name').match(/\[(\d+)\]/);`

Then you can pull out the match at index 1.

Comment: Thank you Josh.  I was (like everyone mentioned below) missing the closing "/".  And this expression is of course cleaner.  I appreicate the help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp covers regexp. You may also want to see the String object (match()). In case you hadn't realized the use of (), when you get your "index" value, it is actually an array. The elements of the array match, in order of left paren, the parenthesis pairings embedded within the regex. So index[0] gives the full match as a string and index[1] gives the string consisting of the part captured within the parenthesis (ie, "14").
try the url: javascript:index=/hell(owo)rld/.exec("helloworld"); alert(index[1]);

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing the closing `/` in your regular expression

```
index = Id.attr('name').match(/\[\d\d?\d?\]/);
                                           ^ need this closing /
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CGnUz/

Also, @Josh M. has a better regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
index = Id.attr('name').match(/\[\d\d?\d?\]);
```

You forgot to add the / at the end.